# Append .csv to Feature Class (missing polygon geometry)

Tags: append, gis, arcgis, esri

When I run an append geoprocessing tool, everything else copies correctly but the geometry is lost and the Shape length and area is "Null".

Original Feature Layer:

[image]

After I delete the old attributes in the feature layer and append the.csv data, I'm still getting "Null" values.

Appended layer:

[image]

Not sure what else to do.